# What is the maximum number of times an RGB LED could be made to flicker between RGB repeatedly in a second with currently available technology?

Tags: led

So RGBRGBRGBRGBRGBRGBRGBRGBRGBRGB…………………………………………

Also, at what rate would the flickering significantly impact the lifespan of the LED ??

Comment: Depends on the LED and what circuit is driving it. Do you have a specific LED in mind?

Comment: You're aware that there's not really any such thing as an "RGB LED", and that actually there are three LEDs just in the same package.

Comment: If you're actually talking about addressable LEDs (which consist of a driver chip with a serial interface and 3 LED chips in one package) then the answer will be different. They may already 'flicker' imperceptibly fast to adjust the apparent (to human eyes) brightness level, however the serial interface limits how fast you can change the colo[u]r or brightness.

Comment: Please _edit your question_ with enough information to clarify this.  Specifically, tell us what parts you're planning on using, or tell us that you're starting from a blank sheet of paper, or whatever.  The company I'm currently working at modulates LEDs at 24MHz, and we only stop there because we don't need to go higher.  _If_ you're starting with three discrete LEDs and you are in control of the board layout, you can do that, too.  If you're starting from someone's module, then chances are you will be _entirely constrained_ by the capabilities of the module.

Comment: @TimWescott Sounds interesitng. Lifi stuff?

Comment: Continuous-wave lidar.

Comment: @TimWescott nice! That's a clever use of LED bandwidth!

Answer (score 8):

> Also, at what rate would the flickering significantly impact the lifespan of the LED ??

I'm not aware of flickering having any influence on LED lifetime.

> What is the maximum number of times an RGB LED could be made to flicker

No such thing exists. "RGB LEDs" are actually three LEDs in one package. Hence, the answer is "same rate as you can make any single LED flicker".

And we can modulate *laser diodes*, which are self-amplifying light-emitting diodes with specific dimensional and material constraints directly (as in, turn them on and off) in [~15 €](https://www.heise.de/preisvergleich/rockstable-nachbau-von-ubiquiti-uf-mm-10g-10g-lan-transceiver-rs-tc-uf-mm-10g-a2693104.html?v=k&hloc=de) SFP+ at 11 billion flickers per second for years now, we can, at higher prices, modulate lasers indirectly for "flicker rates" of beyond 100 billion flickers per second (and surprise, the devices that do high data rates for fiber optics do wavelength multiplexing, i.e. they have diodes of different color in one package),

> with currently available technology?

depends on whose lab equipment you're talking about, but if you have the signal source, ca 15 € buys you a laser diode that you can flicker 11 billion times per second, a driver circuit for that diode, and power conditioning for both:

[image: SFP+ transceiver]

The laser diodes that are in such SFP+ modules are not RGB. But that doesn't really matter – you can buy the [chips that are inside optical transceivers](https://www.ti.com/product/ONET1151L) separately, and just attach the red, green or blue LED of your choice to it.

Note that layout of circuitry at that rate, choice of diode packaging, and choice of device design for high speeds takes knowledge that you might not already have, but that is definitely industry-standard, and thus widely available technology.

## Conclusion

If you mean "flicker" as in something so fast that humans can, or can nearly, still perceive it: As fast as you like, for decades. Modulating a simple LED a couple thousand times a second is no technical challenge at all. (Your infrared TV remote does exactly that.)

If you mean "flicker" as in "turning the light from very low to very bright to very low, driving the device physics to the edge of the possible in terms of speed", then we're talking about bandwidths above 100 Gigahertz, with very affordable commercial of-the-shelf (COTS) modulators being fast enough to reach beyond 10 billion times a second. However, although technologically easily available (as asked in your question), designing boards, diodes and data sources for these kinds of rates is non-trivial.

Comment: Just thought to mention that even if you have an extremely fast driver, it may not be able to drive a generic random LED that fast if it's just slow, i.e. has stray inductances and capacitances that limits driving it quickly.

Comment: @Justme absolutely, hence the last paragraph – the choice of design and type of LED can be challenging. But honestly, me using "flicker" for gigabaud symbol rates is a bit much anthropocentric, isn't it – can't really speak of something "flickering" (which is a *perceptional* quality) if it happens much faster than the photochemical processes in the perceptive organs would allow to perceive (even if there's derivative terms like *flicker noise* that definitely have little to do with human perception). But, even an early-1980s TV remote control does 38 kHz to a by modern standards slow LED, so,

Comment: I guess, I should add a bit of a layman-TL;DR to the end of the question clarifying that.

Comment: Modulating LEDs is not the same as modulating laser diodes, despite their common heritage. In laser emission mode, much faster modulation is possible than in LED mode. "Turning off the tap" on lasers is much faster, since depletion of optically-excited states is much faster than flushing out minority carriers in LED operation.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast that is true; the thought of this answer was "there's two things you might mean: modulating things so that they flicker to human perception; in that case, both standard LEDs and any microcontroller with a open drain will be faster than any human's perception could be (by orders); or you might really mean: modulating a group of solid-state light emitters, and then we have to look at laser diodes." My wording surrounding "not necessarily the fastest diodes" was more than harmful, let me remove that.

Comment: Good luck finding a visible LED with low enough capacitance for the driver from an SFP module to modulate it at 10 Gbps. It's been years since I worked with LEDs, but the last I heard ~100 Mbps was about the maximum achievable. And even a laser isn't going to get to "above 100 GHz" with direct modulation; transceivers at those rates are using external modulators.

Comment: @ThePhoton external modulators: yep, hence my wording that you can *indirectly* modulate the laser (and not the laser diode) for higher speeds. Re: LEDs being slower: I hoped my edit after WhatRoughBeast's comment clarified that; the answer intends to say "you can do human-perceptible Flicker low-tech with an LED. If your flickering speed is about the technologically possible for light emitting solid state devices, then look towards laser diodes (as in cheap IM SFP+ 10GBASE pluggables), and if you need to be really really fast, external modulators.

Answer (score 5):

I've modulated short LED strips at > 1 MHz with reasonably good results. For a R, G, B sequence on a single triplet several hundred KHz to perhaps a few MHz should be possible with good driver design and diode selection.

Comment: KHz == Kelvin-Hertz. You mean kHz.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies a package of Red, Green and Blue diode that is to be driven in a high-frequency flicker.

While @MarcusMuler deals with the diode and electrical part of the question, it is good for "pure" LEDs and laser LEDs only.

The usual type of R/G/B diodes made for visual/illumination purposes (and not for applications like data transmission where quick response is more important than the favorable spectrum) contain phosphor layer that is WAY slower than the diode itself.

If this is the case, one can run them at 10kHz at best and generally way lower, probably as low as 2-5kHz.

Well, one can drive them as quick as they please and the diode under the phosphor will do its best, but this will not be visible from the outside.

Comment: RGB diodes rarely if ever contain a phosphor layer, and most common LED phosphors have a excited state lifetime on the order of tens of nanoseconds. This is why you can still modulate white LEDs at up to a few MHz. The term phosphor here is somewhat misleading, it refers to general light emission rather than the long excited state phosphorescence process you're thinking of. An actual phosphorescent material would not work with an LED since in the excited state it would become transparent for an extended period of time, so short lifetime doped crystals are used instead.

Comment: @user1850479 looks like I have some obsolete image of modern LEDs. I will definitely try a white LED at 1MHz.